# How to make a REST call to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to get going with Magento 2's REST API interface, and I did the following:

1. I made a new "Integration", which gave me the Consumer Key and Secret and the Access Token and Secret.
2. I setup a call like this (using an external REST tool):

   ```
   GET https://[url]/rest/[code]/V1/categories
   Content-Type: application/json
   Authorization: Bearer <Consumer Secret>
   ```

But I always get this HTTP400 error:

```
{
"message": "Specified request cannot be processed.",
"trace": null
}
```

Which does not give me much info on where I am going wrong.

How can I make REST calls to my Magento 2 setup, using the integration keys?

Comment: It should probably be just https://[url]/rest/V1/categories

Comment: @ЗахарJoe thanks, that worked, weird that the docs keep talking about that code

Comment: I've stumbled upon similar inconsistencies in the official Magento docs while working with REST. Sometimes it may be better to look elsewhere, such as tutorials and examples and look in the docs afterwards.